# Exclude Laravel-specific values from request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-form

I want to run `json_encode($request->all())` after a form is submitted, however the returned array is "polluted" with `_method` and `_token` values.

Is there any neat way to exclude the framework-specific fields from the generated json?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$request->only('username', 'password');
```

or

```
$request->except('_method', '_token');
```

Source:
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_only

Comment: Something to note: both this answer and the one below convert the `request` to an array which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Request class provides just that

```
$request->except('_method', '_token')
```